# getJSONObject error: JSONObject["..."] is not a JSONObject

Tags: java

I'm trying to parse a JSON string, but getting an error when trying to get a nested object:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);

System.out.println(jsonObject);
System.out.println(jsonObject.keySet());
System.out.println(jsonObject.getJSONObject("matches"));
```

Below is the output in console. As far as I can see, the JSON is valid as jsonObject is created without an error. But when I try to obtain "matches" it throws an error. I've compared my code with tutorials but I can't see what the issue out to be:

```
{"matches":[{"id":233028,"awayTeam":{...

[matches, count, filters, competition]

Error in client: JSONObject["matches"] is not a JSONObject.
```

Anything I'm doing wrong? Happy to provide any further info if needed.

Comment: I think the error was pretty clear `JSONObject["matches"] is not a JSONObject.` one small point missing that it is an `array`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`matches` is an **array**, not an object. Use `getJSONArray`:

```
System.out.println(jsonObject.getJSONArray("matches"));
```

(Or more usefully:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(jsonObject.getJSONArray("matches")));
```

since `System.out.println` on an array doesn't really show useful information on its own.)